# Why does IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL appear after installing a driver?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-8

I have just installed TP-Link Wireless card TL-WN781ND onto a HP 2310EA Desktop pc that runs on Windows 8. After installing the driver the message `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` appeared. I have removed the card and tried to restore it to the last point before the card was installed - and I'm getting nothing. It won't restore it appears that the operating system has been wiped out.

Comment: "I'm getting nothing" is not a helpful problem description. Does that mean no display? It won't boot? Or what? Similarly, "It won't restore it" isn't helpful either. *What* won't restore *what*?

Comment: You should be able to uninstall the driver in [safe mode](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-boot-into-windows-8-safe-mode/). If its uninstaller does not run, you can try uninstall the device through device manager (**right** click on the bottom left corner of the screen, where the start thingy would show up). You might want to choose the "Delete the driver software..." option. If you can't see that device, follow [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315539).